# Sort org-mode links by descriptive text?

Tags: org-mode

I have a dozen org-mode links in the standard format.  How can I sort these by the descriptive text?

```
[[alink1][Baz]]

[[alink2][Foo]]

[[alink3][Bar]]
```

These are displayed like this in the buffer:

```
Baz

Foo

Bar
```

The result should be:

```
[[alink3][Bar]]

[[alink1][Baz]]

[[alink2][Foo]]
```

Which will be show as:

```
Bar

Baz

Foo
```

[Update]

When I do this: (setq org-descriptive-links t) then try M-x org-sort-list, I get error message: 'Wrong type argument: number-or-marker-p, nil'

[image]

Comment: `org-sort-list` can take a function as parameter, which must return either a string or an integer used with the sort function. We could write a function that returns the descriptive text…

Comment: You screen shot shows that the first list marker `-` is actually part of the link text.  This is what triggers the error.  Move it outside the link, and then `org-sort-list` will work.

Comment: Actually, the problem is that I selected the region instead of simply placing the cursor on one of the lines.  I debugged it from this other answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/805491/2122052

Comment: @AndrewSwann And yes, for some reason org mode always has me in the middle of the description for the first line so any '-' or '+' is inserted into the description, which does cause a sorting problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of is to store your links in an Org list

```
- [[alink1][Baz]]
- [[alink2][Foo]]
- [[alink3][Bar]]
```

and use `M-x` [`org-sort-list`](http://orgmode.org/worg/doc.html#org-sort-list) with the point somewhere in this list. As far as I can tell this works if [`org-descriptive-links`](http://orgmode.org/worg/doc.html#org-descriptive-links) is set to `t`.

**Update:**

As pointed out by @Ehvince, one can also use `org-sort-list` with a
custom `GETKEY-FUNC`:

```
(defun my-get-link-text ()
  "Get the description of the first link on the current line."
  (save-excursion
    (if (re-search-forward org-bracket-link-analytic-regexp
                           (line-end-position) t)
        (match-string 5)
      (buffer-substring (point) (line-end-position)))))

(defun my-sort-list-of-links (with-case)
  (interactive "P")
  (org-sort-list with-case ?f #'my-get-link-text #'string<))
```

I also have some code for sorting links in a region (one per line) that does not use any Org functions (just `org-bracket-link-analytic-regexp`), but I don't think that's useful (given these two solutions).

Comment: Nop, it doesn't work

Comment: @Ehvince: It does work for me. Tested (again) using `"emacs -Q"`; Emacs version 24.4.1, Org version 8.2.10.

Comment: Sorry: it doesn't work with org version 7.8.02 Emacs 24.3 and neither does your `my-sort-list-of-links` :( Will try updating Org.

Comment: @Ehvince: What about the second approach (using a custom `getkey-func`)? Still no luck? (I don't think I want to install Org 7.8 to try it myself.)

Comment: still no luck, which is surprising (see second half of my previous comment ;) )

Comment: I get an error: "Wrong type argument: number-or-marker-p, nil"  Emacs 24.4 on Mac

Comment: @h4labs: How did you trigger this error? Did you use `my-sort-list-of-links` or just `org-sort-list`? Can you do `M-x toggle-debug-on-error`, trigger the error and provide a backtrace? (So far I don't have enough information to help you.)

Comment: I tried both. I didn't get any more info when I enabled it.  I put a pic in my question showing the message and that I've highlighted the links.